# Laravel 8 update

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I actually make a project with Laravel 8.
Insert works properly but not update.
I would like it to be possible to update my track.

My controller :

```
public function updateTrack(Request $request, Tracks $track)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        'author' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
        'level' => 'required',
        'type_track' => 'required',
    ]);
    $track->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('AfterTrackUpdate', compact('track'))
        ->with('success','Track updated successfully');
}
```

My view :

```
    @extends('template.header')

<main class="page contact-page">
    <section class="portfolio-block contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
            </div>

            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>
                                {{ $error }}
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif

            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('AfterTrackUpdate', $track->id_track) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                @method('PUT')
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Nom</label>
                    <input class="form-control item" type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ $track->name }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="author">Auteur</label>
                    <input class="form-control item" type="text" id="author" name="author" value="{{ $track->author }}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="level">Niveau</label>
                    <select class="form-control item" type="text" id="level" name="level">
                        @foreach($levels as $l)
                            @if($track->level == $l->id_level)
                                <option value="{{ $l->id_level }}" selected>{{ $l->name }}</option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{ $l->id_level }}">{{ $l->name }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="type_track">Type</label>
                    <select class="form-control item" type="text" id="type_track" name="type_track">
                        @foreach($tracksType as $tr)
                            @if($track->type_track == $tr->id_track_type)
                                <option value="{{ $tr->id_track_type }}" selected>{{ $tr->name }}</option>
                            @else
                                <option value="{{ $tr->id_track_type }}">{{ $tr->name }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">Modifier</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

My Class :

```
    class Tracks extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Table associée au model.
     *
     * @var string
     *
     */
    protected $table = 'tracks';

    /**
     * Clé primaire de la table.
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_track';

    /**
     * Indique si la clé primaire est en auto-incrément.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $incrementing = true;

    /**
     * Indique si le modèle utilise les timestamps.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'type_track',
        'name',
        'author',
        'level'
    ];
}
```

dd($request->all()) :

```
    array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "HQkkCUjflzRNbMnzmlSNONGExc8Yua8fj0UE4q9g"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "name" => "Braking"
  "author" => "RedLynx"
  "level" => "1"
  "type_track" => "1"
  1 => null
]
```

My route :

```
Route::put('/', [TracksController::class, 'updateTrack'])->name('AfterTrackUpdate');
```

I am redirected to my page but my track is not updated anymore.
If someone can help me please with laravel 8 update i will appreciate thanks.

Comment: Please add the `Tracks` class to your question, the properties you are trying to update are probably not in `$fillable` or are `$guarded`. Also keep in mind that the model name should be singular, so `Track` instead of `Tracks` as name.

Comment: did you check `$track` before updating ? did you check if you remove the redirect that no error appear ? did you check your logs ? did you check the data sent ? Your question and your approach to the issue are missing a lot of details.

Comment: At a glance, everything looks ok. If you're being redirected, it could be from `$this->validate` failing, but you're displaying those validation errors via `@if($errors->any())` block. Do you get any errors listed? Next step is adding some `dd()` or `Log::` statements for debugging (or breakpoints if you can configure and get them running for PHP)

Comment: @TimLewis I get false if i dd($track->update($request->all()))

Comment: Maybe try `$track->update($request->only(['name', 'author', 'level', 'type_track']))`; there might be something in `$request->all()` that isn't playing well with the Model/Update logic.

Comment: @TimLewis Same with this

Comment: Edit your question with `dd($request->all())` and see what's in there, and why that doesn't work with your Model. Consider changing `protected $fillable = [...]` to `protected $guarded = ['id_track']` (i.e. don't allow assignment of `id_track` since it's incrementing). Beyond that I don't know what's going on with this; something in your setup is not working, and you'll have to do more debugging to figure out why.

Comment: @MaartenDev Post was edited with my class

Comment: @TimLewis Post edited.. Changed protected $fillable = [...] to protected $guarded ['id_track']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237645/discussion-between-wakiry-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: Add the fields where you updated to the model to the fillable array. then will be works. sure ;-)

Comment: @MaikLowrey Same with :protected $fillable = [
        'id_track',
        'type_track',
        'name',
        'author',
        'level',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

Comment: Does the validation pass, what is the validation result?

Comment: Could you add the route file? Which action handles the `AfterTrackUpdate` action?

Comment: @MaartenDev Added my route. validation result : array:7 [▼
  "_token" => "SS9tSQFETaOV8bW6pEoCi8p1m9ZF71LxobsdZkeK"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "name" => "test"
  "author" => "test"
  "level" => "1"
  "type_track" => "1"
  1 => null
]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to `update` a `Tracks` instance that doesn't exist, since your Route is missing the `{tracks}` route parameter:

```php
Route::put('/', [TracksController::class, 'updateTrack'])->name('AfterTrackUpdate');
```

Notice how your Controller method has `Tracks $track` as the 2nd argument to `public function updateTrack()`? That is never passed/parsed by your front-end, so it's creating a new `Tracks` instance, and you can't call `->update()` on it, as it's missing a primary key.

If you add Route-Model Binding to your Route, your code should work:

```php
Route::put('/{tracks}', [TracksController::class, 'updateTrack'])->name('AfterTrackUpdate');
```

Edit: If validation fails, it will redirect to `/{tracks}` as a `GET` request. Since you don't have this defined, use a manual validator:

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->input(), [
  'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
  'author' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
  'level' => 'required',
  'type_track' => 'required',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  return back()->withErrors($validator);
}
... // Rest of your Update Logic
```

Just make sure to include `use Validator;` at the top of your `TracksController` to avoid Namespacing issues.

Comment: This works thanks but i got this The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

Comment: That means your validation is failing and is redirecting to you `/{tracks}` as a `GET` request. What is the `GET` method that shows that form? Does it have the same URL?

Comment: I use this route to show edit form : Route::get('/editTrack/{id}', [TracksController::class, 'editTrack'])->name('EditTrack');

Comment: Yeah, so it's a different route entirely. There's an easy answer for that, just use a manual validator, and redirect correctly if validation fails. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks you for help